# How do I enter multiple strings in when asked for in command?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I am learning about using git on my Ubuntu machine. I was going to create a simple bash script to do all of my git commands really easily. I want to be able to automatically enter my username **and** password for my GitHub account, without me as the user having to type them in.

So how do I do this?

Currently, I have found many answers that tell me to use the `yes` command. However, that will only pass through one input though. For example:

```
yes $pword | sudo apt update; yes $pword | sudo apt upgrade; yes $pword | sudo apt autoremove
```

However, when I run `git push -u origin master`, it will ask me for my github username and password. So how can I enter multiple inputs, with the same command?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try `printf 'username\npassword\n' | ... ` although I'm pretty sure `git` has facilities to cache credentials for you - that's probably the right way to go

Comment: Okay, thank you.